# Sync a fork to a specific commit / github release

Tags: github, fork, release

this is most probably a duplicate, if so I'll learn too :) :

If I'm maintaining a fork of a project that has regular releases in github then is there a way of syncing my fork up to a specific release/commit?

These [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork) show how to sync a fork to the upstream project's main, perhaps I'm thinking about it wrong but it seems like if the upstream project employs github releases defined with a tag and a specific commit then it could be useful in some scenarios to follow the releases i.e not always the upstream's master/main's latest commit.

Comment: I tried `git merge <commit id of the upstream release commit I was after>`
 in an upgrade-branch I made in my fork after having configured the upstream project as a remote and doing git fetch as per the mentioned github doc and this seems to have worked.